# Phantom NA's in dataframe when regression in R

Tags: r, dataframe, regression

I have pretty large dataframe -- about 235K rows and I want to do multivariate regression:

```
model <- lm(var~., data=data)
```

but I get an error:

```
Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
  NA/NaN/Inf в 'y'
In addition: Warning message:
In storage.mode(v) <- "double" : NAs introduced by coercion
```

Neither `na.omit`, nor other methods of getting rid of NA's didn't help.

So I've tried to find NA by myself. I've split dataframe into two parts:

**Second UPD**

```
data1 <- data[1:(dim(data)[1]/2), ]
data2 <- data[(dim(data)[1]/2):(dim(data)[1]), ]
```

and I again get result for both `lm` and no errors from previous UPD section! NB: I've restarted RStudio.

**First UPD**

```
data1 <- data[1:(dim(data)[1]/2),]
```

and when I call `lm` instead of previous error I get next:

```
Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
```

To reach this error I reduced data from 235K to 14.5K. So, what is the problem now? Some of offcasted slices don't throw any errors.

**Origin version**

```
data1 <- data[1:(dim(data)[1]/2)]
data2 <- data[(dim(data)[1]/2):(dim(data)[1])]
```

and call `lm` for each of them:

```
model1 <- lm(var~., data=data1)
model2 <- lm(var~., data=data2)
```

and I reciece no errors! So, I suppose problem is in big size of dataframe. Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: You are subsetting by columns. So your are splitting the data "vertically". The amount of rows is the same in `data1` and `data2`. What is the amount of columns in the dataframe?

Comment: Try `lm(var~., data=data[complete.cases(data), ])`.

Comment: what does `str(data)` give?

Comment: @Sandwichnick, there are 14 columns, and yeap, I've forgotten an comma in the end. So now I have another error, I've updated the question.

Comment: @jay.sf, nope, that doesn't work, the same error about NA's.

Comment: @rw2, 
```{R}
'data.frame': 235143 obs. of  14 variables:
 $ var0: chr  "0" "0" "0" "1" ...
 $ var1: chr  "8" "11" "18" "10" ...
```
etc.

Comment: Follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: @dragondangun It would help to see the full outputs in your question. It looks like your predictors are coded as "characters". Try converting them to numeric, using `as.numeric()` and then running the model.

Comment: @rw2, thanks! I've used: 
```data<-lapply(data, as.numeric)```
and that's works. You can write it as an answer and I'll mark it as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the outputs of `str(data)` it looks like some of your numeric predictors are coded as "characters".

Re-code them to numeric using `as.numeric` and see if that fixes the issue.

If it does you might want to check why they're coded as characters. Are there rogue punctuation or spaces in your data?